# xmlenc support in Python

Tags: python, xml, encryption, xml-encryption

I have a xml messaging based API written in Python. Now there is a need to support xmlenc (https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core/) and I see very little information over the web about how to bite the problem.
Is there any hope for my cause? Like any library? Or should I go and ask Java people to do a external 'decryption parser' (which I rather not)? I assume it's easier in Java (Scala).